# using rs(next) but got TYPE_FOWARD_ONLY in SQLite

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I try using SQLite after sucessfully used mysql database on simple CRUD java programs
using this driver: http://cdn.bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar i got this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: SQLite only supports TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY cursorsException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at tes.MainForm.Tampil(MainForm.java:31)
```

mainform.java:

```
private void Tampil(){
    try{
        int row = tabel.getRowCount();
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
            tabeldata.delete(0, row);
        }
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT * from asu";
            ResultSet rs = c.script.executeQuery(sql); // line 31

        while(rs.next()){
            DataPegawai d = new DataPegawai();
            d.setNo(rs.getInt("no"));
            d.setNip(rs.getInt("nip"));
            d.setNama(rs.getString("nama"));
            d.setDivisi(rs.getString("divisi"));
            d.setLevel(rs.getInt("level"));
            tabeldata.add(d);
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.print(e);
    }
}
public MainForm() { 
   initComponents();
    c = new DBConnection();
    tabeldata = new TabelData();
    tabel.setModel(tabeldata);
    Tampil();
}
```

DBconnection.java:

```
public class DBConnection {      
    Connection c = null;
    Statement script; 
    public DBConnection(){
        try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/titit2.db");
            script = c.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            System.out.println("Koneksi Sukses");
        }catch(  SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex){
            System.err.print(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I think i only use rs(next),did i miss something?

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Comment: sorry,i edited the questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `DBConnection` you shouldn't specify `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, but specify `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` instead as SQLite doesn't support scroll insensitive (or scroll sensitive).

The problem is not occurring at line 31, but in `DBConnection` where you are **ignoring** the `SQLException`, and then continue to use the `script` field which is `null`. This then triggers a `NullPointerException` at line 31.

This isn't immediately clear because 1) you ignore the `SQLException` and 2) use `System.out.print` which doesn't add a linebreak. Instead you should use `printStackTrace()`.

Comment: Thank you very much,after changing my code from:
`script = c.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);`
to:
`script = c.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);` its works like charm

i really had no clue about this resultset,will read it later
thanks